# Different between WAMP and web hosting?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp, hosting

I have planned to learn WordPress. I just want to know what will be core difference between functionality and features if I install it on WAMP that is local host and a web server?

My preference was WAMP but I am not yet sure.

Answer (score 1):

When doing web development on your local machine using a localhost, there are a few things you need to be aware of.

- You need to ensure that it is same as the versions of the products on your actual web server or close to it (MySql, Apache, Php, etc.)
- You need to be aware of the urls you use compared to the urls when deployed to the server (in Wordpress, you need to edit the main web urls in your mysql dump file before uploading to your webhosting)
- WAMP actually is easy to configure, other alternative is XAMPP for local development
- Wordpress updates a lot and usually so is there requirements, so in order for wordpress functions to work properly, your local server must be updated to their requirements or at least close to it